# React create element type invalid after including router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I have added react router it gives me follow errors
[image]

here is main.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Home = require("./components/homePage");
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router >
        <Route component={Home} path="/"></Route>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Homepage.js

```
var React = require('react');
var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div >
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

There are many others questions related to same problem but none of them address the real issue or general reason or cause.
other answers suggesting using react-router 4 alpha and i have tried beta4 but still same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string, but got: object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729972/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-but-got-object)

Comment: according to mentioned question installed beta-4 but still not working

Comment: Are you working in Node.js?

Comment: yes node gulp browserify and other junk

Comment: What do you have in `package.json` file when in question is react-router?

Comment: react-router@4.0.0-beta.4  installed using npm install --save react-router@next

Comment: When I proposed changing the value I actually meant to decrease the value. Some tutorials I read mentioned that. I will try to show you the link @owaishanif786.

Comment: Let me show you the URL....

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iAG6h9ff5s&t=158s, try something like 1.17, ... :)

Comment: I suggest you use at least for some new project the new [React.Component ES6 architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058241/which-reactjs-syntax-to-use-react-createclass-or-es6-extends/41966499#41966499)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing React Router components wrongly, it should be:

`var Router = require('react-router').Router`

`var Route = require('react-router').Route`

Comment: after trying import { Router, Route } from 'react-router' the app worked so i came to know your syntax was right. As the first time i have tried i changed only in one file and the error was triggering from multiple file but I was unable to find due to bundle.js giving no hint from which file error happened.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question like yours, but tricky you cannot say it is a duplicate, at least the error is the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729972/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-but-got-object).

Based on the ES5 syntax you are using I guess your example is old. Try using the different version of the React Router.

Or just start with some new ES6 syntax React Router example.

Comment: according to mentioned question installed beta-4 but still not working. there is no syntax error